# How to upgrade TeX Live 2016 to 2017?

Tags: installing

I have noticed that TeX Live 2017 has been released. But I am using 2016 version. Is there any way to upgrade 2016 to 2017 without installing fully 2017 version?

Comment: Short answer: No.

Comment: The consequence of @TeXnician's short answer: you have to unistall the former and install the latter. Given this, have you considered not upgrading as far as you don't really need it?

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis That's wrong. You do not *have* to uninstall, you  *can*.

Comment: Then it wouldn't be a manual *upgrade*, don't you agree? :P

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis what are you talking about? TeXnician mentions that you do not have to uninstall tl16 in order to install tl17, they live side by side.

Comment: @daleif, my second comment was an attempted joke (if you keep `Aold` and install `Anew`, technically you aren't upgrading `Aold`, since it is still there, as old as it was).